# Using captum with nn.Embedding getting RuntimeError

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using captum library and getting following error. Here is the complete code to reproduce the error.

> RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from captum.attr import IntegratedGradients

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

vocab_size = 1024
embedding_dim = 32
seq_len = 128
num_classes = 5
hidden_dim = 256

class predictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim 
        self.vocab_size, self.embedding_dim = vocab_size, embedding_dim

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embedding_dim)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.seq_len*self.embedding_dim, self.num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x.long())
        x = x.reshape(-1, self.seq_len*self.embedding_dim)
        x = F.relu(self.linear(x))
        return x

class wrapper_predictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x
    
indexes = torch.Tensor(np.random.randint(0, vocab_size, (seq_len))).to(device)

model = predictor().to(device)
wrapper_model = wrapper_predictor(model).to(device)

ig = IntegratedGradients(wrapper_model)
attributions, delta = ig.attribute(inputs=indexes, target=0, n_steps=1, return_convergence_delta=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue with LayerIntegratedGradients.

Here is the link to read more to know other possible solutions. https://captum.ai/tutorials/IMDB_TorchText_Interpret

This is using an instance of LayerIntegratedGradients using forward function of model and the embedding layer as the example given in the link.

Here is sample code which using LayerIntegratedGradients with nn.Embedding

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from captum.attr import IntegratedGradients, LayerIntegratedGradients
from torchsummary import summary

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

vocab_size = 1024
embedding_dim = 1
seq_len = 128
num_classes = 5
hidden_dim = 256

class predictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(predictor, self).__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim 
        self.vocab_size, self.embedding_dim = vocab_size, embedding_dim

        self.embedding = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embedding_dim),
        )
        self.embedding.weight = torch.randn((self.vocab_size, self.embedding_dim), requires_grad=True)
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.seq_len*self.embedding_dim, self.hidden_dim, device=device, bias=False),
            nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.num_classes, device=device, bias=False),
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x.long())
        x = x.view(-1, self.seq_len*self.embedding_dim)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

class wrapper_predictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1) #keep softmax out of forward if attribution score is too low.
        return x

model = predictor().to(device)

indexes = torch.Tensor(np.random.randint(0, vocab_size, (seq_len))).to(device)
input_size = indexes.shape
summary(model=model, input_size=input_size, batch_size=-1, device='cuda')

wrapper_model = wrapper_predictor(model).to(device)

lig = LayerIntegratedGradients(model, model.embedding)
attributions, delta = lig.attribute(inputs=indexes, target=0, n_steps=1, return_convergence_delta=True)
```

Comment: What is the difference here? requires_grad=True for self.embedding.weight?